# Footer Border vertical lines alignment

Tags: html, css

Hi This is my website please take a look into footer http://www.abiglittlebiz.com/trevelle/

I want the vertical line exactly like this.

[image: Please see this image]

here you can see my website footer which I am trying to change
footer.html this is my footer

```
<footer>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 seven-three">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 customer">
      <h3>Customer Service</h3>
            <p>Unit 36/65 Marigold St,Revesby
            NSW 2212 <br>
            P | (02) 9773 8773
            <br>
            F | (02) 977 8125
            <br>
            E | info@trevelle.com.au</p></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 company">

      <h3>The Company</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="ourprofile.html">Our Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="home.html">Home Designs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="showcase.html">Showcase</a></li>
                  <li><a href="commercial.html">Commercial</a></li>
                  <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="toc.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
              </ul></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 dc">

      <h3>Our Display Center</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Freemans Ridge Estate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Homeworld Camden South</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Brooks Beach Estate Horsley</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 lp"> 
<h3>House & Landing Packages</h3>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">House & Landing Packages</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Display Homes for sale</a></li>
      </ul>
                </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 nl">
      <h3>Newsletter</h3>
    <p>Be the first to know about Trevelle Special offers</p>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
    <form>
        <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required="required" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
            </button>
    </form>
<h4>Join The Conversation</h4>
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
<p class="join">Join Us in the conversion on property we are active on facebook</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copyright">
    <h3>Copyright @2015</h3>
    <p>Site designed by</p>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: [**Please see this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need some equal padding for its contents. Add this following CSS:

```
.seven-three .customer h3,
.seven-three .customer ul,
.seven-three .company h3,
.seven-three .company ul,
.seven-three .dc h3,
.seven-three .dc ul,
.five-two .lp h3,
.five-two .lp ul {margin: 0; padding: 0 10px; position: static;}
.seven-three .customer h3,
.seven-three .company h3,
.seven-three .dc h3,
.five-two .lp h3 {padding-top: 15px;}
```

For equal height:

```
.seven-three .customer,
.seven-three .company,
.seven-three .dc,
.five-two .lp {height: 350px;}
```

This is just for resetting and adding right CSS. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: but the borders are still not equal

Comment: @Dennis Can you give a `height: 350px` above, see the updated answer. **http://i.imgur.com/WjS2uWz.png?1**

Comment: works perfect. one thing more if you look into that image there is copyright and site designed by text. I have added it like this <div class="copyright">
    <h3>Copyright @2015</h3>
    <p>Site designed by</p>
</div>
but I cant set their border above.

Comment: @Dennis I can't see it. Give me a few mins?

Comment: I am unable to see the copyright @Dennis. Where have you put. Have you updated the live version?

Comment: please check the post again I have added my footer.html code